# Bizarre Wordpress CSS update problem

Tags: css

So I went and updated a line in layout.css twice.  Then, I undid those changes.  I'll call the different versions "CSS original, CSS 1, CSS 2".

Now I'm experiencing a problem where my browser is using the wrong css.  I cleared my browser's cache, but the problem still persists.  I thought it might be caused by server-side caching, but for some reason different browsers are using different versions of the same CSS: Firefox is using CSS 1 and Chrome is using CSS 2.  I have no idea what could be causing this problem, and this happens on different computers too.

EDIT: Found the problem, it was caused by a plugin called "Supercacher".  I purged the cache and it works now.

Comment: Please answer your question rather than edit it with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was caused by a plugin called "Supercacher", which must have been caching my css files. I purged the cache and it works now.